# elasticsearch filter by length of a string field

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to get records the has in 'title' more then X characters.

NOTE: not all records contains title field.

i have tried:

```
GET books/_search
{
    "filter" : {
          "script" : {
              "script" : "_source.title.length() > 10"
          }
      }
}
```

as a result, i get this error:

```
GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[Cannot invoke method length() on null object
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Be careful with this solution. Access to _source has a lot of performance issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to take into account that some documents might have a null `title` field. So you can use the groovy null-safe operator. Also make sure to use the POST method instead:

```
POST books/_search
{
    "filter" : {
          "script" : {
              "script" : "_source.title?.size() > 10"
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom tokenizers to count the number of characters. Check this answer for a possible help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47556098/463846