# Elasticsearch Edge-NGrams Prefer Shorter Terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I like the results I am getting from Elasticsearch using [Edge-NGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) to index data and a different analyzer for searching. I would, however, prefer that shorter terms that match get ranked higher than longer terms.

For example, take the terms `ABC100` and `ABC100xxx`. If I perform a query using the term `ABC`, I get back both of these documents as hits with the same score. What I would like is for `ABC100` to be scored higher than `ABC100xxx` because `ABC` closer matches `ABC100` according to something like the [Levenshtein distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

---

Setting up the index:

```
PUT stackoverflow
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
            "number_of_shards": 1
        },
        "analysis": {  
            "filter": {
                "edge_ngram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": "1",
                    "max_gram": "20"
                }
            },

            "analyzer": {
              "my_analyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": [
                  "edge_ngram"
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    },

    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "product": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inserting documents:

```
PUT stackoverflow/doc/1
{
    "product": "ABC100"
}

PUT stackoverflow/doc/2
{
    "product": "ABC100xxx"
}
```

Search query:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "product": "ABC"
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.28247002,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stackoverflow",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.28247002,
        "_source": {
          "product": "ABC100xxx"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stackoverflow",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.28247002,
        "_source": {
          "product": "ABC100"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I may have a shorter term such as `ABC100` ranked higher than `ABC100xxx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding plenty of [less than optimal solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041575/elasticsearch-filter-by-length-of-a-string-field) regarding storing field length as a field or using a script query, I found [the root of my problem](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ngram-filter-and-relevance-score/22475/2). It was simply because I was using the edge_ngrams token filter instead of the the edge_ngrams tokenizer.