# Increasing score of documents with shorter field length in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

We have an ElasticSearch index with a custom analyzer used for indexing. It has standard `char_filter` and `tokenizer`, and this custom filter (amongst irrelevant others):

```json
"custom_ngram": {
  "type": "edge_ngram",
  "min_gram": "2",
  "max_gram": "25"
}
```

The mapping is only a simple `name` text field.

There are three documents in the index:

```json
{"id": "1", "name": "Thun"}
{"id": "2", "name": "Thunder"}
{"id": "3", "name": "Thunder Dome"}
```

For search, we use another analyzer that's identical to the indexing one, minus the custom ngram filter.

When searching for "Thu" on the name, the documents "Thun" and "Thunder" will have the same score as they have identical Term Frequencies. As a newcomer to ElasticSearch I was surprised as I assumed "length of field" in the TF computation was counting characters when it actually count terms. So "Thunder Dome" does score lower.

In our case, we'd like "Thun" to score higher than "Thunder" as the searched term covers a higher percentage of the characters of the field. What is the best way to accomplish this?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49619408/352876) to a similar question suggests setting `custom_ngram` as a tokenizer rather than a filter, but this only solves the issue of the searched term appearing sooner or later in the field.

An idea that came to mind is to index `name` as a keyword and add a function score that gives a boost inversely proportional to `doc['name.keyword'].length()`, but I'm not sure it's the cleanest approach.