# how to query string field length in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

how to range query in string fields in elasticsearch 6.2? or create a field in mapping when indexing time to calculate string length and store it on other field?

i work on it in different ways:

1. using painless script >> not works
2. using custom character_tokenizer with 1 ngram min/max >> not works; honestly it's works but the driven result not real and different with real length, probably it's for indexer and analyzer.

my sample data is twitter api for tweets and i want to find those tweets who 140 characters in text field.

Comment: You could use the _update_by_query API to create a new field and store the length after indexing. You probably don't need to store it, then use a script query to get the length

Comment: what script query? can you help

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041575/elasticsearch-filter-by-length-of-a-string-field